# Why I get error in PHP?

Tags: php

I have function in php and call it as:

```
<?=$this->lib->_get(array(9), array($value->id))?>
```

I get error in this line:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion
```

If do `var_dump($value->id)` I get:

```
string(34)
```

Comment: Does `$this->lib->_get()` accept two arrays or an array and a string? Either the first or second parameter should be a string, not an array.

Comment: Yes, by default there are two arguments as: `array(), array()`

Comment: Do you have this on a loop? maybe in one of the iterations you are receiving an array

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `array($value->id)` by `$value->id` because it looks like your function requires an string as second parameter.

Be also sure that the `_get` function requires an array as first argument.

Comment: No I can not it should be array

Comment: This is function: `public function _get($category = array(), $subcategory = array()){}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the value inside of the function.
You should provide more information about the library you are using, maybe the body of the function will help
What happens when you send an array with more elements?

Comment: If do `var_dump($array)` inside function: `array(1) { [0]=> int(9) }`

Comment: Still is unclear, try to put the body of the function and you should try to setup a break point inside the function to get the moment when the problem comes up
I repeat more information about the library or function will help